# Any way to suppress "Summary of failures for Google Apps Script" emails?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script that customers install using the "run script as user" option. Unfortunately, my script has a try/catch block around all of the code but it seems that occasionally errors still slip by and customers receive a "Summary of failures for Google Apps Script" email (usually just due to a temporary Google server error).

Is there any way to permanently suppress these emails from being delivered to customers of Google Apps Script applications (or redirect them to the script developer)?

Comment: Are these email notification of errors from a trigger?  Those can be disabled.

Comment: Yes. This is a time based trigger but I don't want each user that installs my script to have to manually disable the error notifications themselves. I'd like to do that programmatically for them.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here. You can either [disable the error message being emailed when the trigger fails](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#errors_in_triggers), or instead you can see if you can [get your Application published as an Add on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish), as Add-ons are the 'Official' publication, and don't allow End users to receive any backend error messages.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My app allows users to install it themselves at which point it creates a new trigger for each user. Is there a way to disable error messages at the time the trigger is created? Or would every user have to manually disable the error messages?

Comment: If it is at all possible, your answer would be in managing the triggers programmatically (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically). You may be able to add some code that fires every few hours to delete any triggers that were created.

Comment: Well, I actually don't want to delete the created triggers. Those need to run every so often for every user. I just wanted to never send an email to the user if there was an error. Unfortunately, according to the following link, it looks like each user would have to disable the error notification themselves: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#errors_in_triggers

Comment: Unfortunately, if that's the case, I think you're only options are to attempt to have it released as an Add on as I linked in my answer, or advise users to disable it manually. Don't think there's an alternative.